# Como identificar linha de td para montar um data-title dinâmico

Tags: javascript, css

Estou montando uma tabela responsiva com alinhamento vertical em que o css insere via:`content: attr(data-title);` o valor do campo thead(**th**).

HTML desejado

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb0">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Codigo </th>
           <th>Nome </th>
           <th>Telefone </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="Código">113244</td>
          <td data-title="Nome">Fulano da Silva</td>
          <td data-title="Telefone">+55 11 3213213</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML relidade

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb0">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Codigo </th>
           <th>Nome </th>
           <th>Telefone </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="Código">113244</td>
          <td data-title="Código">Fulano da Silva</td>
          <td data-title="Código">+55 11 3213213</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('th').each(function() {
  $('td').attr('data-title', $(this).text());
});
```

CSS

```
#no-more-tables td::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
}
```

Seria possível utilizar um modo dinamico, onde cada *data-title* seja referente seu thead th?

Comment: Olá Kim. Procure marcar as respostas das suas perguntas. Se não sabe como funciona, consulte a página [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itere primeiro os titulos, depois faça nas tr, veja abaixo:

```js
var headers=[];
$('th').each(function() {
   headers.push($(this).text());
 // $('td').attr('data-title', $(this).text());
});


$('tr').each(function(i, tr) {
  var tr =$(tr);
  tr.each(function(j, td) {
       $(td).attr('data-title',headers[i-1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb0">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Codigo </th>
           <th>Nome </th>
           <th>Telefone </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="Código">113244</td>
          <td data-title="Nome">Fulano da Silva</td>
          <td data-title="Telefone">+55 11 3213213</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Da forma que está fazendo (`$('td').attr('data-title', $(this).text());`) irá alterar todos os `td`'s de uma vez a cada volta
>   no laço.

Você consegue percorrendo cada `th` e alterando o respectivo `td` do `tbody` pelo índice `(i)` gerado pelo laço `.each`.

O seletor `:eq()` busca o elemento pelo seu índice na coleção, ou seja, o primeiro `th` está ligado ao primeiro `td` porque ambos possuem índice `0` nas suas coleções:

```js
$('thead th').each(function(i) {
   
   $(this)                                // th do loop
   .closest('thead')                      // pai thead
   .next('tbody')                         // próximo tbody
   .find('td:eq('+i+')')                  // busca o "td" com o índice da vez
   .attr('data-title', $(this).text());   // altera o atributo
});

// a linha abaixo é apenas um exemplo para
// verificar no console os atributos alterados
console.log($("tbody").html());
```

```css
#no-more-tables td::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="no-more-tables" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="">113244</td>
          <td data-title="">Fulano da Silva</td>
          <td data-title="">+55 11 3213213</td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```